# kubuntu: kwallet forgot my luks passwords after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: luks, kwallet

upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.
mostly went fine.
however, i had an encrypted partition which i just could click the folder in dolphin and it would autofill the password but since the upgrade it keeps asking me for it.
since i have gotten so used to the autofill i have no idea anymore what i initially used for password to this luks partition.
not sure why the upgrade wiped the kwallet password but i need to get into that partition.
is there anyway to recover the password?

kwallet has a lot of entries but not for the id of this particular partition.

i did a blkid and this is the partition:
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="8e420671-d41d-4c13-8215-1d3fc7663926" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="e0308ccf-02ae-4695-b2b7-f36913b8a332"

but neither uuid or partuuid is in the kwallet.

why did this happen and is there any hope of recovering the password?